# GCP Machine Learning job: how to print lines to .csv output file?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tensorflow, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

On GCP Machine Learning, I'm trying to run a training job, with intermediate output to a .csv file. I'm using Tensorflow in python.

Here's what I've tried so far:

1.

```
with open('gs://<bucket>/<file>', 'wt') as csv_file:
```

... throws exception: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

2.

```
gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                      'w',
                      content_type='text/plain',
                      options={'x-goog-meta-foo': 'foo',
                               'x-goog-meta-bar': 'bar'},
                      retry_params=write_retry_params)
  gcs_file.write('abcde\n')
  gcs_file.write('f'*1024*4 + '\n')
  gcs_file.close()
```

... throws exception `from google.appengine.api import app_identity ImportError: No module named appengine.api`

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For option (1), if you are using TensorFlow, you can use `tf.gfile.Open("gs://...", mode="w")` to open a file in GCS for writing.

The `tf.gfile` module uses TensorFlow's C++ I/O layer, which includes supports for reading from and writing to GCS. The built-in Python `open()` function will only open files in the local file system.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are writing code for the App Engine environment, but are you sure that is the correct environment to be writing code for?

If you are using regular GCP instances you should probably use [one of the other APIs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-basics#storage-upload-object-python).

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_blob(bucket_name, source_file_name, destination_blob_name):
    """Uploads a file to the bucket."""
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)

    blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)

    print('File {} uploaded to {}.'.format(
        source_file_name,
        destination_blob_name))
```

Edit: replaced API link

Comment: Simple and elegant answer.